# JPA Native Query

Tags: jpa, nativequery

I am trying to execute a native query and pass run-time parameters and get the result as a List. When I try to process the Object [], one of the columns fetched is a String. But it comes out as java.lang.Character instead of String. Here is the query below:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (TRUNC(abm.credit_card_expiration_date) BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE) AND
              trunc(last_day(SYSDATE))) THEN
          'Expires'
         ELSE
          'Expired'
       END EXP_STATUS,
       TO_CHAR(abm.credit_card_expiration_date, 'MM/YY') EXP_DATE
  FROM account_billing_methods abm
 WHERE abm.account_id = 201103
   AND abm.billing_type_id = 1
   AND TRUNC(abm.credit_card_expiration_date) <= TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
```

The EXP_STATUS column could not be typecasted into String as it is of type Character. Any ideas of why it does not work?

Regards,
-Anand

Comment: Is it a `Character` or a `Character[]`?

Comment: even String.valueOf(Obj [0]) only resulted in the first character of the fetched columne i.e. 'E'

Comment: getClass.getName() says it is of type java.lang.Character

Comment: What JPA provider are you using, sounds like a bug

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and changed the select clause of my query to:
`EXP_STATUS || '' as EXP_STATUS`

Then it is a VARCHAR instead of a CHAR and JPA will return it as a String instead of a Character.

If someone knows a better/more elegant solution, I would appreciate if you could share it.

Comment: Worked like a charm